# Pinch to zoom in Google Maps in Firefox affects webpage rather than the map

Tags: google-maps, firefox, windows

I use Google Maps in Firefox 39 on my Dell Vostro laptop with Windows 7. When I try to pinch to zoom (on the touchpad), the entire webpage zooms in and out instead of the map itself. In other words, the zoom action is intercepted by Firefox instead of delegating the action to Google Maps.

Is there any way to have Firefox delegate the zoom action to Google Maps without disabling the pinch-to-zoom gesture in Firefox altogether? I mean, I want "zoom-aware" web apps to handle zooming themselves, and let Firefox handle the zooming for "non-zoom-aware" websites. Is this possible?

I should note that if I try to scroll instead of pinch (by swiping the right hand side of the touchpad vertically) then Google Maps zooms in and out correctly, but I still prefer to pinch to zoom.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated here. This seems to be a browser problem, not a Web App problem. Even if it's the latter, that's probably something the developers need to address and not something fellow users can help with. Does it work properly with other browsers?

Comment: @ale I agree. It's kinda like this entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118267/pinch-to-zoom-on-embedded-google-map-zooms-whole-page I'll find an answer

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User three times. I’m voting to close this question because this is a troubleshooting question related to the operating system and input devices. It belongs to [su].

Answer (score -1):

If you don't specify explicit `gestureHandling` for the 2D Map then it can happen that the map element defaults to "greedy" behavior. This can surely happen if your map is not inside an iframe. With greedy behavior the map will hijack more gestures than in "cooperative" mode. See [Controlling Gesture Handling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#controlling_gesture_handling).

When the gesture handling is greedy than you won't see the *"Use two fingers to move the map"* message over the 2D Map when you scroll over it with flick gestures. In such cases explicitly specifying `cooperative` gesture handling helps, although it may not fix the problem fully, because the issue is also browser dependent. Even with cooperative I may see a little page zoom on Android Chrome based browser, but the behavior is much better.

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom,
  center,
  gestureHandling: "cooperative",
});
```

Comment: The question is an end-user troubleshooting question. Considering this, the answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rubén I ran into the same exact phenomena, and a software engineer can improve it somewhat (as shown in my code). If a website doesn't have that, then the zooming experience can be worse.